# Add bxslider in magento 2 home page

Tags: magento2, javascript

as i am new in the magento and i want help to add bxslider in the home page area.

I have added the widget-block from the admin to display the slider images.

Also I have added the js in `default_head_block.xml` file. but it does not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after 1 day.

**Perform below step to add bxslider in Magento 2**

1. Add the requirejs-config.js in your theme root directory with below code

   `var config = {
       shim: {
           'bxSlider': {
               deps: ['jquery']
           }
       },
       paths: {
           'bxSlider': "js/bxslider"
       }
   };`
2. Add bxslider.js(Rename bxslider.min.js to bxSlider.js), Wrap your bxslider js code in the

   `define([
     "jquery"
   ], 
   function(jQuery) {
     "use strict";
     "Your bxslider js function goes here"
   });`
3. Add the bxSlider function in phtml file as below.

   `<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
       require([
           'jquery',
           'bxSlider'
       ], function($){
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('.slider').bxSlider( {
                   controls: true
               });
           });
       });
   </script>`
4. Please clear all the cache from admin. Also delete the "pub\static\frontend\Vendor_name\Theme_name"

Hard Refresh Your Store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your **bxslider.js** file

Wrap all the code between `require` function.

See the example given below.

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    // your bxslider js code
});
```

Comment: so you mean i need to add the jquery.bxslider.min.js code between above comment?

Comment: Yes. As of now, If you check console tab in your browser, there will be an error like **'bxslider is not a function'**. You have to require jquery first. Try my answer and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: require([
    'jquery',
  ], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    jquery(".slider").bxSlider(
      {
        controls: true
      }
    );
  });

I have put this code in logo.phtml but still not working. Also i have load the jquery.bxslider.min.js in default_head_block.xml .

Answer (score 0):

You can try OwlCarousel instead of bxslider :

https://hweb87.wordpress.com/2018/09/04/how-to-call-owl-carousel-in-magento2/